How to show login page when accessing the site with Blazor server web app with .NET 8.0
I created a Blazor server web app with .NET 8.0 and authentication type Individual Accounts. The web app code is generated automatically by Visual Studio 2022. Everything works fine as expected.
However I would like to change the code so that when a user accesses the web app, it shows the login page and makes sure the user is authenticated before he/she can access the content of the web site.
UPDATE: Thanks to Fengzhi Zhou, adding @attribute [AllowAnonymous] to login.razor fixes the problem.
I have tried to add the following lines (according to a suggestion on Google search)
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]

to _imports.razor according a suggestion on Google search but I got an error - can't read this page
"It looks like the webpage at https://localhost:7145/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%......"
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

UPDATE
Yes you are right that my previous answer is lack of consideration. Meanwhile I misunderstood the error of repeated redirections. Yes you can add the lines to _imports.razor it is correct.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]

Then you need to add AllowAnonymous to your Login.razor to avoid it under the same auth control.
//to your login.razor
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

Now every page is accessed only after logged in.

You can add the code in the components that you want to keep from users not authenticated.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]

The _Imports.razor is not used like that.  It allows you to define a set of namespaces that you want to import globally, making those namespaces available to all components within your application without explicitly importing them in each component.
Which means you can add the code in this way, the same effect.
1.Add in _Imports.razor.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

2.Add in components you want to limit accessibility.
@attribute [Authorize]


Hi Fengzhi, thanks for the reply. The user needs to be authenticated before he can see the web content, it is not practically to add @attribute [Authorize] to every page.

@peter I have updated my answer , please check if it is suitable for your problem.

Hi Fengzhi, it works! Adding @attribute [AllowAnonymous] to login page fixes the problem. Many thanks. I have marked this as an accepted answer.

The @attribute [Authorize] tag is to label a page/component that you need to be authenticated in order to view the content, however this will not redirect you to the login page if you are not logged in and does not work in the _imports.
So if I understand you correctly you would like to redirect the users to auth before they get to the page with the @attribute [Authorize] attribute.
You can achieve this by adding a check to your "MainLayout.razor"
Here is an example of the a code behind:
    public partial class MainLayout
    {
        //Gets context that contains auth state
        [CascadingParameter]
        private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
        
        //Injects Nav Man to redirect
        [Inject] private NavigationManager? NavMan { get; set; }
       
        
        /// <summary>
        /// On Init
        /// </summary>
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            //Check if user is logged in
            if (HttpContext == null || HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false && HttpContext.Request.Path != "/Account/Login")
            {
                //Redirects if not logged in
                NavMan!.NavigateTo("Account/Login",true);
            }
            
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
    }


Hi Ruan, thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but it did not work, the login page failed to load. However your code does gives me some ideas, I moved the code to the home page, it worked in the home page. Still I need to find a solution to work for every page.

So if you have the auth redirect on mainlayout then you can add the authorize on each page like before as the login will be forced once you hit the site. Can you provide browser console error perhaps or logs if you hit the home page?

With your code in mainlayout, here is the error:

With your code in mainlayout, the error is localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. However have just found out that your code can be fixed by changing the if condition to if (HttpContext == null || (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false && HttpContext.Request.Path != "/Account/Login")). With this fix, there is no need for the @attribute [Authorize] attribute in _import or any page.
